# Dynamically add custom control on Xpage

Tags: xpages

how can I add custom control on the basis of sessionScope variable. I try include page container control but no luck:

```
<xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put("viewName","ccViewAll.xsp");}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.get("viewName")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xc:appLayout>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel xp:key="facetMiddle">
            <xp:include id="include1">
                <xp:this.pageName><![CDATA[${javascript:sessionScope.get("viewName")}]]>
                </xp:this.pageName>
            </xp:include>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:appLayout>
```

The above code give me error Error 404 HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception. But when I hardcode the viewname that is ccViewAll.xsp instead of sessionScope.get("viewName"), its work fine.

-MAK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this to show a different view in the domino database based on some other selection that I would suggest looking at the Extension Libraries 'Dynamic View Panel' control.

Using this control means you won't need to create different custom controls for each view that you want to use, just a single page with this control and point it to the correct view to display via a scope variable.

If you need to customize how each view displays you can create a viewControl bean to set additional properties based on the view that it is showing.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. Thanks Declan Lynch

Answer (score 4):

You can use the dynamic content control or the switchFacet control if you have the ExtLib for XPages. The Teamroom template (demo application that comes with the ExtLib) uses these in the "allDocuments" Xpage or the "allDocsAllTab" custom control, these are good examples to look at.

If you don't have the ExtLib you could use the loaded / rendered property of a custom control to decide which one gets loaded.

e.g.

```
<xp:panel key="MiddleColumn">
   <xc:customControl1 loaded="${javascript: if(viewScope.control == "customControl1")}"></xc:customControl1>
   <xc:customControl2 loaded="${javascript: if(viewScope.control == "customControl2")}"></xc:customControl2>
</xp:panel>
```

loaded = false means that nothing will be done for this control.
rendered = false means that the control will be created but hidden, you can change this later to show it.

use rendered if its going to change for example when a button is clicked and loaded when its decided at start up and won't change while the user is logged in.

Comment: How can I debug my viewScope variable? When I put in computed field it shows the value of that variable but when I compare it in rendered it always return false!!!!   [code]  <xc:ccViewAll>
     <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[${javascript:if(@Contains(viewScope.get("viewName"), "ccViewAll.xsp")){
 return true;
}
else{

 return false;
}}]]></xc:this.rendered>
    </xc:ccViewAll>[/code]. I sluse if(viewScope.get("viewName") == "ccViewAll.xsp")

Comment: in severnside script use "print("viewScope: " + viewScope.control);" This will print a line to the server console, the same idea as system.out.println in java, add as many of these as you need to find the issue. Just FYI you can do the same client side with a browser console and "console.log("Test: " + test);"

Comment: one thing to note about javascript is the difference between #{javascript: }  and ${javascript: } .  # means it will be run each time the control / page is refreshed, $ means it will only be executed on page load. if your creating that viewscope at the top of the page your rendered property is probably running before its created. change the rendered to #{javascript: }

Comment: @AshfaqKhatri there is a nice OpenNTF project called dBar. Xpages debugger. Makes it easier to debug your scoped variables. 

http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/29b713283ca92bf5862570ef00653b4e/dfe484b6d6364f2786257984003d171d!OpenDocument

Answer (score 0):

Something worth to mention is that if you don't use the ExtLib - If you're using Partial Refresh then you HAVE to use the rendered property, since the loaded property only can be calculated on pageLoad.

From my understanding this means that every custom control will be computed by the server and that's probably not something you want. (Added overhead, for one thing.)

/J